# Replace linebreak in specific piece of text in file

Tags: php, regex

We have a firewall in place, of which we process the configuration with a PHP script and then make it available to look at on a website.

Today an issue occured. The issue lies in the comments field. There should be no linebreak in there. So I looked to PHP to remove the linebreak (replace it with a space) in the comments field.

My experience with regex is limited, but I've built quite some using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) and the help of [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) posts. For some reason, this one I can't seem to solve.

The configuration is stored in a text file, which looks like this:

```
config firewall policy
    edit 2
        set uuid 79123-123-51e6-bb5f-123f123df
        set srcintf "any"
        set dstintf "any"
        set srcaddr "h-host1" "h-host2" "h-host3"
        set dstaddr "all"
        set action accept
        set schedule "always"
        set service "ALL"
        set utm-status enable
        set logtraffic disable    
        set comments "This is a comment for this rule
 This is an additional comment for that rule"
        set ips-sensor "Sensor1"
    next
    edit 1
        set uuid f123-34ab-1dcf-a123dc123
        set srcintf "any"
        set dstintf "any"
        set srcaddr "all"
        set dstaddr "all"
        set action accept
        set schedule "always"
        set service "ALL"
        set utm-status enable
        set logtraffic all
        set comments "This is a one line comment for a rule"    
        set ips-sensor "Sensor1"
    next
end
```

In this example there is 1 comment that has a linebreak.
The regex I tried, is stored over here: https://regex101.com/r/0jaDjL/1/

What it should do, is look for **"    set comments"** and then the next quote **"** , so then the linebreak in the text in between, can be replaced with a space.

So this here:

```
        set comments "This is a comment for this rule
 This is an additional comment for that rule"
```

Becomes this here:

```
        set comments "This is a comment for this rule This is an additional comment for that rule"
```

The regex seems to grab the correct pieces online: https://regex101.com/r/0jaDjL/1/

But not in my environment. PHP for example doesn't know the 'g' parameter. And it seems to find the last quote, instead of the first next one.

To better see what happens, my coding now looks like this:

```
<?php
function blaat($matches){
    echo '<pre>';
    echo PHP_EOL .'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA#'.$matches[0].'#AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
    echo PHP_EOL .'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB#'.$matches[1].'#BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB';
    echo PHP_EOL .'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC#'.$matches[2].'#CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC';
    echo PHP_EOL .'DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD#'.$matches[3].'#DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD';
    echo PHP_EOL .'EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE#'.$matches[4].'#EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE';
    //echo PHP_EOL .'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF#'.$matches[5].'#FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF';
}
$PathAndFile='C:\Temp\sys_config.txt';

preg_replace_callback(
    '/^(\s*?)(set comments ")(\X+)("$)/Um',
    'blaat',
    trim(file_get_contents($PathAndFile)) 
);
```

But the output is not what I hoped for.

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA#
        set comments "This is a comment for this rule
 This is an additional comment for that rule"
        set ips-sensor "Sensor1"
    next
    edit 1
        set uuid f123-34ab-1dcf-a123dc123
        set srcintf "any"
        set dstintf "any"
        set srcaddr "all"
        set dstaddr "all"
        set action accept
        set schedule "always"
        set service "ALL"
        set utm-status enable
        set logtraffic all
        set comments "This is a one line comment for a rule"#AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB#
        #BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC#set comments "#CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD#This is a comment for this rule
 This is an additional comment for that rule"
        set ips-sensor "Sensor1"
    next
    edit 1
        set uuid f123-34ab-1dcf-a123dc123
        set srcintf "any"
        set dstintf "any"
        set srcaddr "all"
        set dstaddr "all"
        set action accept
        set schedule "always"
        set service "ALL"
        set utm-status enable
        set logtraffic all
        set comments "This is a one line comment for a rule#DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE#"#EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

Any tips on how to replace the linebreak in the comments field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a (nested) call to `preg_replace_callback()` here:

```
<?php

$regex = '~^\s*set comments\s\K"[^"]*"~m';

$data = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($match) {
    return preg_replace("~\R\s*~", " ", $match[0]);
},
$data);

echo $data;
?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/2CzYuc) and [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/0jaDjL/2) for the expression.

---

Explanation for the expression:

```
^             # match start of the line in multiline mode
\s*           # zero or more whitespaces
set comments  # set comments literally
\s            # whitespace
\K            # "forget" what's been matched thus far
"[^"]*"       # anything between double quotes ("...")
```

---

The first expression looks for your blocks in question, the inner expression replaces the newlines and possible consecutive spaces with a single space.
To replace *all* consecutive whitespaces with only one space, change the inner expression to:

```
return preg_replace("~\s+~", " ", $match[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @Jan
Just tried this, and it works great. 
I'll further analyse this to see what you did exactly.

Comment: @Paddy: Added an explanation for the regex here. Don't forget to upvote the other answers as well if they helped you (arrow up, that is).

Answer (score 1):

You can make a simpler regex for that, just select all text between quotes after `set comment "` and replace all new lines with spaces in the matches.
Here is how regex works: https://regex101.com/r/AU2VJJ/1

And here is the php demo you can play with:

```
<?php
$text = <<<EOT
config firewall policy
    edit 2
        set srcintf "any" 
        set comments "This is a comment for this rule
 This is an additional comment for that rule"
        set ips-sensor "Sensor1"
    next
    edit 1
        set srcintf "any"
        set comments "This is a one l
ine comment for a rule"    
        set ips-sensor "Sensor1"
        set comments "This is a comment for this rule
 This is an additional comment for that rule
And one more."
    next
    edit 3
        set srcintf "any"
        set comments "This is a one l
ine comment for a rule"    
        set ips-sensor "Sensor1"
        set comments "This is a comment for this rule
Another comment
More comments
And more
And more
And one more."
    next
end
EOT;

$text =  preg_replace_callback('/(set comments ")([^"]+)(")/', function($matches) {
    // $matches[1] is `set comments"` text
    // $matches[2] is everything between `set comments"` and closing `"`
    // $matches[3] is closing `"`
    return $matches[1] . str_replace("\n", " ", $matches[2]) . $matches[3];
}, $text);
echo $text;
```

Comment: When executing it like this, all linebreaks in the file are replace. But, nonetheless I'll analyse what you did here. To see what I can learn.
`$text =  preg_replace_callback('/(set comments ")([^"]+)(")/', function($matches) {
    return $matches[1] . str_replace("\n", " ", $matches[2]) . $matches[3];
}, file_get_contents($PathAndFile) );
$text = str_replace("\n", "AA", $text); // had to replace \n with <br> to verify in browser
echo $text;`

Comment: Just remove `$text = str_replace("\n", "<br>", $text);` line from the code, and there won't be new line replacements